# Function changes the value of the given argument

Tags: c, function, pointers

I'm passing the `Test` variable that I declared in my main function to *tf* function. If I make a change to the `argument` in `tf`, the actual `Test` variable changes.

Is there any way to prevent this without creating another variable in the `tf` function?

## The Code

```
#include <stdio.h>

void tf(char *argument){
    argument[0] = 'Z';
}

int main() {
    char Test[5] = "Hello";
    printf("'Test' before calling tf function : %s\n",Test);
    tf(Test);
    printf("'Test' after calling tf function  : %s\n",Test);    
    return 0;
}
```

## The Output

```
'Test' before calling tf function : Hello
'Test' after calling tf function  : Zello
```

I googled the problem but I didn't found anything useful.

Comment: "Prevent"? then what would this function do?

Comment: Don't tag unrelated languages! /// @12431234123412341234123 Despite also tagging C# and C++, the title says this is a C question.

Comment: `char Test[5]` should be `char Test[6]` or just `char Test[]`. You forgot to save space for the NUL.

Comment: `char Test[5] = "Hello";` has no nul terminator: it isn't a valid C string that can be passed to `printf`.

Comment: Please learn what a pointer is and what arrays are and how array variables decay to pointers.

Comment: You could use `void tf(const char *argument){ … }`, but then the assignment inside the function would be rejected by the compiler.  If you pass an array to a function, the contents of the array can be changed by the function — this should be covered in your textbook.  (If it isn't covered, get a better textbook.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For starters:
On my computer your code displays garbage.

This is wrong, it reserves 5 chars and the length of "Hello" is 5, so there is no room for the terminating NUL character:

```
char Test[5] = "Hello";
```

Don't specifiy the length but let the compiler do it's job:

```
char Test[] = "Hello";
```

---

That being said, it's normal that the first character is modified into 'z', `argument` points to your original string. What do you expect?

There is no way to prevent this without creating another variable in the `tf` function, you need to make a copy of the string and operate on the copy.

But the question here is: what are you *actually* trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

You don't change the argument, you change the memory where the argument is pointed to. For avoiding it, make the parameter to point to const:

```
void tf(const char *argument) {
    argument[0] = 'Z';  // Compile time error
}
```

Comment: Re “You don't change the argument”: Technically, the argument in the function call is the array, `Test`. As part of evaluating the function call expression, the array is converted to a pointer to its first element, and the `argument` parameter of `tf` is initialized with that value. Then `tf` changes a character where `argument` points, and that changes the `Test` array (specifically an element in the array, which is part of the array). So it is true that `tf` changes the argument `Test`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want two copies of the string, you will need to store it somewhere. Whether you make the copy inside or outside the function is up to you.

For example,

```c
void tf( const char *argument ) {
    char *copy = strdup( argument );
    copy[0] = 'Z';
    // Do something with `copy` here.
    free( copy );
}
```